# In an array how can one check if any two of its content numbers can add up to a certain value x or not?

Tags: c, arrays

What command could one use to check if the sum of any two numbers within an array add up to a certain value of x.

Comment: You have not any array in your code.

Comment: You can write `j = size` instead of `for(i = 0; i < size; i++) j = i + 1`.

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must __describe the specific problem__ — and __include valid code__ to reproduce it — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://SSCCE.org) for guidance.

Comment: @user3015922, `y + z == x`?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution should help you:

```
int TestArray (int array[], int count, int targetSum)
{
    int i,j;

    for (i=0; i<count-1; i++)
    {
        for (j=i+1; j<count; j++)
        {
            if (array[i] + array[j] == targetSum)
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This function takes as arguments the array, the number of array elements (3 in your example), and the target sum to check for (5 in your case).

Usage is like this (sample main):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int numbers1[] = {1,2,3,4};
    int numbers2[] = {1,1,3,3};
    int result;

    result = TestArray(numbers1, 4, 5);

    if (result == 1)
    {
        printf("True");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False");
    }

    result = TestArray(numbers2, 4, 5);

    if (result == 1)
    {
        printf("True\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("False");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> True
>
> False

Comment: Ok - that's easy enough to fix - I've updated the code above to pass using array notation instead instead. If this isn't allowed, just move the code to main!

Answer (score 0):

according to your example

Beginners practice..

```
int arr[3] = {1,2,3};    //array has 3 numbers
int i,j,x,k;
int res = 0;

scanf("%d",&x);

for(i=0; i< size; i++){
    j = i+1;
    if(j >= size){
        j = 0;
    }
    k = arr[i] + arr[j];

    if(k == x){
        res = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if(res  == 1)
    printf("True\n");
else
    printf("false\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
int i;
int j;
int x;
int [size] TheArray;

printf("Enter value of x: ");

scanf("%d", &x);

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        if(TheArray[j]+TheArray[i] == x)
        {
            printf("true");
            break;
        }
        else printf("false");
    }
}
```

You need to include the array in your code, he is the main actor in your problem.

Comment: `int [size] TheArray;`?

Comment: That is only guaranteed to work if the target sum is odd. If the target were 4, and the array were {2,0,0}, your code would hit true on the first loop, as it adds same-indexed values to themselves.