# How to determine if there in the list 2 elements with provided sum?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, search

On interview I was asked to write method with following contract:

```
boolean checkList(List<Long> list, long sum){...}
```

for example it has to return **true** for arguments:
 `({1,2,3,4,5,6}`, `9`)  because 4+5 = 9

and it have to return **false** for arguments:

`({0,10,30}`, `11`)  because there are no combination of 2 elements with sum 11

I suggested code like this:

```
boolean checkList(List<Long> list, long expectedSum) {
    if (list.size() < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int k = i; k < list.size(); k++) {
            if ((list.get(i) + list.get(k)) == expectedSum) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But interviewer asked me to implement one more solution.

I am not able to create a better solution. Can you ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In an array how can one check if any two of its content numbers can add up to a certain value x or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112419/in-an-array-how-can-one-check-if-any-two-of-its-content-numbers-can-add-up-to-a)

Answer (score 0):

Also give hashing a shot. There are more solutions to this problem located [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/).

```
// Java implementation using Hashing 
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.HashSet; 

class PairSum 
{ 
    static void printpairs(int arr[],int sum) 
    {        
        HashSet<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(); 
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; ++i) 
        { 
            int temp = sum-arr[i]; 

            // checking for condition 
            if (temp>=0 && s.contains(temp)) 
            { 
                System.out.println("Pair with given sum " + 
                                    sum + " is (" + arr[i] + 
                                    ", "+temp+")"); 
            } 
            s.add(arr[i]); 
        } 
    } 

    // Main to test the above function 
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    { 
        int A[] = {1, 4, 45, 6, 10, 8}; 
        int n = 16; 
        printpairs(A,  n); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner using java-8 :

```
public boolean checkList(List<Long> list, long expectedSum) {
    Set<Long> hashSet = new HashSet<>(list);
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                    .anyMatch(i -> hashSet.contains(expectedSum - list.get(i)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   public static boolean checklist(List<Long> list, long expectedSum) {
    if(list.size() < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    HashSet<Long> hs = new HashSet<Long>();
    for(long i : list) {
        hs.add(i);
    }

    for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++) {
        if(hs.contains(expectedSum - list.get(i))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This brings your algorithm to linear time rather than quadratic

Answer (score -1):

maybe look at each number and see if the total minus that number is in the list
so

```
boolean checkList(List<Long> list, long expectedSum) {
    if (list.size() < 2) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if(list.contains(expectedSum-list.get(i))){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Like Shubhendu's answer above, this is essentially the same as the OP's code, just with the inner loop hidden in the `contains()` function.